# GPS not getting user location in iphone

Tags: ios6, xcode4.5, cllocationmanager, mkmapview

I developed GPS app. Its an background running app. I used Xcode 4.5 with ios 6 for it.I am getting  the data but some times it shows me an alert "Failed to get your location" while running app on ios device. I checked another location app on device but it never shows me like this..

Comment: Can other applications get a location? At the same time as your application can't?

Comment: try any application that uses GPS in your device and check its result

Comment: Yes I checked another application it gives me the location. Only my application results it.

Comment: Now fine... its working properly...